# Django - Connection refused mysql on ubuntu subsystem windows 10

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I'm using xaamp for MySQL DB and I run my server on both cmd and ubuntu subsystem but my ubuntu says

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111 "Connection refused")')

[image: More Detail]

Answer (score 1):

The reason is SubSystem Ubuntu is in another network layer. So those cannot connect.

```
Connecting to Windows network applications/servers from Ubuntu in WSL2
WSL2 is actually running on a separate, virtualized, NAT'd network from your Windows host. As such, you need to determine the proper IP address to use for the Windows host in order to connect to it from the WSL2 network.

Assuming a default WSL/Ubuntu installation on a supported Windows release, mDNS is usually the best option.

The mDNS name of your Windows host that you can use from within Ubuntu will look like:

MyComputerName.local
As long as you haven't changed the DNS resolver from the WSL default, that will be the same as what you see when you run hostname in Ubuntu.

You can determine this programmatically by:

Obtaining the hostname in your programming language / environment
Appending .local
For instance, in Bash, to connect to a Windows MySQL server:

Install the MySQL client in Ubuntu:

sudo apt install mysql-client
Connect to Windows MySQL server via "$(hostname).local":

mysql --hostname=$(hostname).local --user=me -p mydb
```

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411512/how-to-connect-local-windows-applications-like-conda-and-mysql-from-ubuntu-on-ws